Injected service in Controller is undefined
I'm tring to inject a kafka message producer service into my controllers (the kafka service is available under a shared backend project in the monorepo)
The kafka producer in the shared-be:

@Injectable()
export default class KafkaProducerService {
  constructor(private readonly kafkaService: KafkaService) {}

  createMessage<K>(data: MessageWithPartition<K>): Message {
    return {
      key: data.key ?? crypto.randomUUID(),
      timestamp: Date.now().toString(),
      value: JSON.stringify(data.message),
      headers: data.additionalHeaders,
      partition: data.partition,
    };
  }

  async produceMessage<K>(
    topic: string,
    messageWithPartition: MessageWithPartition<K>
  ) {
    try {
      console.log(messageWithPartition);
      logger.log(`Sending a message to topic [${topic}]`);
      return await this.kafkaService.getProducer().send({
        topic,
        compression: CompressionTypes.GZIP,
        messages: [this.createMessage(messageWithPartition)],
      });
    } catch (error) {
      logger.error(
        `Error happened during sending Kafka message to topic [${topic}]: ${error.message}`,
        'produceMessage'
      );
      throw error;
    }
  }
}


the kafka service in shared-be:
@Injectable()
export class KafkaService
  implements OnModuleInit, OnModuleDestroy, IKafkaProducer
{
  private kafkaClient: Kafka;
  private producer: Producer;
  private consumers: Consumer[] = [];

  constructor(@Inject('KAFKA_CONFIG') private config: KafkaConfig) {
    this.kafkaClient = new Kafka({
      clientId: config.clientId,
      brokers: config.brokers,
      retry: config.retry,
    });

    this.producer = this.kafkaClient.producer({
      allowAutoTopicCreation: config.allowAutoTopicCreation || true,
    });
  }
  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.initProducer();
    await this.initAndRegisterConsumers();
  }

  async onModuleDestroy() {
    await this.producer.disconnect();
    await Promise.all(this.consumers.map((consumer) => consumer.disconnect()));
  }

  private async initProducer() {
    await this.producer.connect();
    logger.log('Kafka producer is up and running');
  }

  private async initAndRegisterConsumers() {
    if (this.config.consumers) {
      for (const consumerClass of this.config.consumers) {
        const consumerInstance = new consumerClass();
        const consumer = this.kafkaClient.consumer({
          groupId: consumerInstance.groupId,
          sessionTimeout: this.config.kafkaSessionTimeoutMs,
          heartbeatInterval: this.config.kafkaHeartbeatIntervalMs,
        });
        await consumer.connect();
        await consumer.subscribe({
          topic: consumerInstance.topic,
          fromBeginning: consumerInstance.fromBeginning,
        });
        await consumer.run({
          eachMessage: async ({ topic, partition, message }) => {
            await consumerInstance.handle({ topic, partition, message });
          },
        });
        this.consumers.push(consumer);
      }
    }
    logger.log('Kafka consumers are up and running');
  }

  getProducer(): Producer {
    return this.producer;
  }
}


This is the kafka.module.ts:
import { DynamicModule, Module } from '@nestjs/common';

import { KafkaConfig } from './interfaces/kafka.interface';
import { KafkaService } from './kafka.service';
import KafkaProducerService from './kafka-producer.service';


@Module({})
export class KafkaModule {
  static forRoot(config: KafkaConfig): DynamicModule {
    return {
      global: true,
      module: KafkaModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: 'KAFKA_CONFIG',
          useValue: config,
        },
        KafkaService,
        KafkaProducerService,
      ],
      exports: [KafkaProducerService],
    };
  }
}


And then in my project I'm trying to make my own instance of the kafkaModule by doing:
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { KafkaModule } from '@monorepo/platform/shared-be/kafka';

import { AdapterModule } from './adapters/adapter.module';
import ControllersModule from './controllers/controllers.module';
import {
  ClientInfoConsumer,
  ClientRegisterConsumer,
} from './lib/kafka/consumers/gateway.consumers';
import { PrismaModule } from './lib/prisma/prisma.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    KafkaModule.forRoot({
      clientId: env.KAFKA_CLIENT_ID,
      brokers: env.KAFKA_BROKER_LIST,
      kafkaHeartbeatIntervalMs: 3000,
      kafkaSessionTimeoutMs: 10_000,
      retry: {
        initialRetryTime: 300,
        retries: 10,
      },
      consumers: [ClientInfoConsumer, ClientRegisterConsumer],
    }),
    DipocketModule,
    PrismaModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AdapterController],
  providers: [ClientRegisterConsumer, ClientInfoConsumer],
})
export class AppModule {}


So after this in the AdapterController I'm trying to inject the KafkaProducerService by doing:

@Controller('psp-gateway')
export default class AdapterController {
  constructor(private readonly kafkaProducerService: KafkaProducerService) {
    console.log('kafkaProducerService is:', kafkaProducerService);
  }


And I get Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AdapterController (?). Please make sure that the argument KafkaProducerService at index [0] is available in the ControllersModule context.
I tried removing the Inject as well from the controller dependency injection but in that case its just results in undefined. What am I missing?
I also have "emitDecoratorMetadata": true in my tsconfig.json

you've declared the KafkaProducerService provider in the dynamic module KafkaModule.forRoot but you forgot to make that dynamic module global, otherwise you'll have to import that dynamic module again into the ControllersModule instead of its static version (which doesn't has the provider you're trying to inject)
So add global: true to the return of KafkaModule.forRoot and drop the import KafkaModule from ControllersModule because it's pretty useless.

Unfortunately that didn't make a difference, updated the post with your suggestions, thanks! Also got rid of the controllers module and included it in the app module straight to make it a bit simpler and small change in the AdapterController I got rid of the @Inject(KafkaProducerSevrice) as ideally I shouldn't inject that directly

can you update the error message as well? it doesn't seems correct
